# search file with Writer permission

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive API V3 [Query string examples](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#query_string_examples).

I am trying to search Files for which user `"something@example.org"` has write permissions.

It works if email account is in gmail domain like test@gmail.com. On folder home has given permissions to 2 users one is test@gmail.com and other is test@yahoo.com when i search for 'test@yahoo.com' in writers it does not bring any file/folder

When I search for 'test@gmail.com' in writers it brings files. Both users have Role Editor on folder. Does this work only for gmail accounts and not for accounts outside the domain?

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en):

> Important: If you share a file with an email address that isn’t a Google Account, they can only view the file.

So essentially, the yahoo address does not have any write permissions to the file, hence the response you are receiving from the API.

#### Reference

- [Share files from Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en).